# How to begin a document numbering with a number other than 1?

Tags: pages

I'm making a large document in separate docs. I want to number the second doc from 21 on. It will only allow me to start at 1. Any fixes?

Comment: Which Pages version? And I assume you are talking about page numbering, right?

Answer (score 4):

On **Pages '13** :

- Go on Setup (Top right corner)
- Section thumb
- Start at '21'

[image]

---

On **Pages '09** :

- Show inspector
- 2nd thumb
- Section
- Start at '21'

[image]